# how to use macro definition in sweet.js?

Tags: sweet.js

I'm new to sweet.js. I'm able to run example in [official tutorial](http://sweetjs.org/doc/1.0/tutorial.html#_introduction), but not in [this tutorial](http://jlongster.com/Writing-Your-First-Sweet.js-Macro) because it uses macro definition:

```
macro foo {
  rule { $x } => { $x + 'rule1' }
}
```

I'm not sure whether this code is supposed to be processed by `sjs` or some other tools. `sjs` gave me:

```
Error: not a valid expression
__=>__ $x + rule1
```

What am I doing wrong?

*sweet.js v2.2.1 on node v6.9.4*

Answer (score 0):

Got it myself. It's the method in v0.7. From v1.0 it only allows definition using `syntax`.